# How to use PrincipalPermission attributes after authorizing user in Custom userNamePasswordValidationMode method?

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF REST service that *successfully* calls a custom method to validate the credentials sent by the client using Basic authentication. Configuration like so:

```
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
 customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="RESTfulSecuritySH.CustomUserNameValidator,
 RESTfulSecuritySH" />
```

Now upon calling that method my user is validated, and the following *is* populated with all of the user's information *:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity
```

However, once this method completes and the control passes on to the *originally requested RESTful method* (i.e. GetData or something), the value in `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` is not populated. Because it is *not* populated, I can not use any of the `[PrincipalPermission]` attributes on the methods as I would like.

However `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity` *is* populated with my user's credential information (name, IsAuthenticated), but this does not appear to  map over to `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` or the `[PrincipalPermission]` attributes. I know I can poke around in the `ServiceSecurityContext` in code to determine if the user is authorized, but I wanted to use an attribute on the method instead if possible.

Therefore if I apply any `[PrincipalPermission]` attributes it always fails with the message: **"Request for principal permission failed."** Which makes sense because `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` is no longer populated. My guess is after the call was finished to my custom `Validate` method the Thread lost it's context.

Regardless, my overall question is can the `[PrincipalPermission]` be used somehow after calling a customUserNamePasswordValidatorType method?